# How to convert str into an int in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

How can I convert my decimal message in 3 digits from str into an int? I've tried `print(int(list1))`, but i got error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '136 462 380 542 525 933 949 347 185 849 942 359 177'`

Here's my code

```
def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
Message = "66a9b2d0b1baf7932416c65a28af3c89" 
print("Hexa message: ", s)

decimal = hex_to_decimal(s)
print("Decimal message: ", decimal)


#Divide decimal message into 3 digits
n = 3
list = [str(decimal)[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str(decimal)), n)]
list1 = ' '.join(list)
print('Decimal message in 3 digits: ', list1 )
print(type(list1))
print(int(list1))
```

Comment: You'd be better off using `str.split()` instead of the string splicing you're attempting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sliced](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)  for spliting string by no of character.

```
from more_itertools import sliced

def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
Message = "66a9b2d0b1baf7932416c65a28af3c89" 
print("Hexa message: ", s)

decimal = hex_to_decimal(s)
print("Decimal message: ", decimal)


#Divide decimal message into 3 digits
n = 3
list_ = list(sliced(str(decimal), n))
list1 = ' '.join(list_)
print('Decimal message in 3 digits: ', list1 )
print(type(list1))
print(int(''.join(list1)))
```

note error you are facing, is because you are converting a list of sting to int, but first you need to join them together to form one single digit then use the int convert option